# Missing ETW EventSource table in Azure SDK 2.6

Tags: azure, etw, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to use ETW for logging with several custom EventSource classes in Azure SDK 2.6.

When testing locally with the compute/storage emulator, three of my custom WADMyEventXYZ tables show up; however, the final expected table "WADMyDataSets" never seems to be created. How should I determine what is causing this problem? I see no errors from the compute emulator when the debugger is attached and stepping through the code in the debugger shows that WriteEntry on the EventSource is definitely called. The other tables show up in SchemasTable in the developer storage account, but there is no entry there for WADMyDataSets.

I exported WADDiagnosticInfrastrureLogsTable into CSV and examined it in Excel and see the following messages that reference "MyDataSets":

> Validating table MyDataSets; DiskMB:451; RequiredQuota:451 RetentionSeconds:7776000 Pri:2 MinQuotaMB:0 RunningTotal:3757
>
> Table does not exist
>
> table C:\Users\Caleb\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\b316f531-f673-4db3-ac1c-e4649e289871\WAD0104\Tables\MyDataSets does not exist, CreationDisposition = 4
>
> Table MyDataSets does not exist, will create a new one
>
> Delaying the creation of table MyDataSets until the schema is known

Later on:

> Converted EventSource provider name "MyDataSets" to {74a2b9c9-0bd8-547f-6cad-453da47055be}
>
> Matched task with query id MyDataSetsQuery and regex ^MyDataSets$ to source table MyDataSets
>
> Registering query MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_XTableWadAccount:
>
> Adding standard PkRk (MA) fields to 'MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets'
>
> Successfully compiled the query 'MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets'
>
> Added task MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_WADMyDataSets_PT1M_XTableWadAccount from MyDataSets - Partitions:-1 Pri:normal TSPolicy:start StoreType:Central Repeat:2147483647 Timeout:3600s Deadline:300s DelayRange:0.00

Later on:

> No checkpoint found for task MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_WADMyDataSets_PT1M_XTableWadAccount after time 2015-05-13T00:44:21.000Z; retry time out is 3600 seconds
>
> First scheduled task for MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_WADMyDataSets_PT1M_XTableWadAccount is at 2015-05-13T01:44:00.000Z (plus a delay of 20s)

Later on:

> Increasing query delay of task MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_WADMyDataSets_PT1M_XTableWadAccount from 20 to 40 seconds to introduce randomness to the upload schedule

Later on:

> Starting scheduled task MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_WADMyDataSets_PT1M_XTableWadAccount from 2015-05-13T01:43:00.000Z to 2015-05-13T01:44:00.000Z; query delay 40 seconds
>
> Table C:\Users\Caleb\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\b316f531-f673-4db3-ac1c-e4649e289871\WAD0104\Tables\MyDataSets does not exist
>
> Ending scheduled task MyDataSetsQuery_MyDataSets_WADMyDataSets_PT1M_XTableWadAccount from 2015-05-13T01:43:00.000Z to 2015-05-13T01:44:00.000Z in 1ms

**Update**

The EventSource in question had one event on it:

```
[Event(1)]
public void DataSetLoaded(string traceActivityId, string userId, string reportCode, long timeToLoadMs)
```

Removing the fourth parameter "timeToLoadMs" resulted in the WAD event table showing up as expected. I tried changing the last parameter to a string, and it failed to show up again. Is there a documented limit on the number of parameters for an event method? I'm pretty sure I've seen samples that have four parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my web project to .NET 4.5.1 and now the WAD table shows up as expected (I had been running on just .NET 4.5 before this).

It would seem that there might be a bug with having 4 parameters on an EventSource event when using .NET 4.5.0.

As a side note, with 4.5.1, I now have the System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.SetCurrentThreadActivityId method which will let me get rid of manually including the CorrelationManager.ActivityId in my event output.

Comment: I am getting a log `Delaying the creation of table ExceptionTable until the first event directed to that table is received`. How can i check why its not receiving any message

Answer (score 0):

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/ConnectOn-Demand/240 video released today says full support for Azure table logging for ETW eventsources.